# How can I disable restrictions and/or factory reset without having the passcode of my Apple TV 4K?

Tags: appletv, settings, 4k, restart

I recently bought an Apple TV 4K at our local electronics store. It functioned perfectly when I started it up, except what I just noticed is that I cannot do a lot of things. After a quick Google this turned out to be the restrictions. When I try to disable this I get asked for a pass code. Very annoying, as I don't know this pass code. A solution to this seems to be to factory reset the Apple TV, but that too is greyed out.

Does anyone know a way to work around this? As I basically just want to factory reset my Apple TV and start over.

Answer (score 0):

> You will have to ask an Apple technician to restore the device.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251453065

Apple TV 4K removed the USB port on the back of the device, so it's not possible to restore the device using a computer without it having been paired to the computer previously.